# Why doesn't this code trigger Sonar's "close resource" violation (squid:S2095)

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarlint

I just found this piece of code, and would have expected Sonar Lint to report a "Resources should be closed" [squid:S2095](https://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3AS2095) issue).

```
try {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("myfile.properties");
        props.load(fis);
        fis.close();
        maxThreadPool = Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty("maxpoolsize", "20"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("unable to property out of properties file", e);
        maxThreadPool = 20;
    }
```

I can see that Sonar Lint scans the file after each modifications (I tried to add other issues and it found them). Also, the issue is active in the selected profile on our Sonar server because it finds resource problems in other parts of the code base.

We are using Sonar 5.6.4, and Sonar Lint 2.7.1.1640 in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2016.3.4.

Can anyone help?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: An important piece of information missing is the version of SonarJava that is installed in SonarQube. I assume you are using the connected mode.